# javaEE application layout

Tags: architecture, jakarta-ee

I've been tasked with writing a new webapp in javaEE, which will be a first for me.  I'm familar with the java language, but all of my previous projects have been in .net.  So I've downloaded netbeans and I'll probably be using Hibernate, and started digging in.  My question is, what's the best way to lay out a javaEE app?  Should all data access go through netbeans?  I was told to use webservices as much as possible so it's easy to pull data in and out of the system, and I've read through tutorials that create webservices in a seperate web application, as compared to the javaEE enterprise application.  Is that really the way it's supposed to work? Just trying to wrap my head around this as compared to what I'm used to in .net.  Thanks!

Comment: "Should all data access go through netbeans?" netbeans is an IDE

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at [Maven](http://maven.apache.org).  Maven has the concept of archetypes that will help you in laying out and building a sample project.  For example, if you are building an EAR file, there is an [archetype for setting up the EAR](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/site.html)

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you to look at these solutions:

1. [AppFuse is a full-stack framework for building web applications on
   the JVM](https://github.com/appfuse/appfuse)
2. [SpringFuse](http://www.jaxio.com/en/celerio.html)
3. [SETTING UP JAVA EE 7 PROJECTS WITH MAVEN 3](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/setting_up_java_ee_7)